# 10001-ое простое число

Tags: c, циклы

Здравствуйте! Решаю задачу с *ProjectEuler*. Нужно найти 10001-ое простое число. Написал код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

bool is_prime(const unsigned long long _num)
{
    bool is_prime = true;

    for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < _num/2; i +=2) {
        if (_num % i == 0 && i != 1) {
            is_prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return is_prime;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    unsigned long long answer = 1;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10001; answer += 2) {
        if (is_prime(answer))
            i++;
    }

    printf("Answer = %llu\n", answer);
}
```

Выдает ответ `104745`, хотя правильный ответ на 2 меньше - `104743`. Разница, как раз, равна числу, которое я прибавляю к `answer` в строке
`for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10001;`**answer += 2**`) {`. Скажите, как это исправить?

Comment: там 1 не считается простым числом

Comment: Извините, уточните пожалуйста, где там?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что цикл выполняется так:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10001; ) {
    if (is_prime(answer))
        i++;
    answer += 2;
}
```

Или так:

```
while( i < 10001 ) {
    if( is_prime( answer ) )
        i++;
    answer += 2;
}
```

То есть выход из него случится после того, как к `answer` в очередной раз прибавили 2.

---

Как вариант (не единственный):

```
while( 1 ) {
    if( is_prime( answer ) ) {
        if( ++i == 10001 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    answer += 2;
}
```

Comment: То-есть единственное решение - это после цикла отнять от `answer` двойку?

Comment: Ну почему же. Можно просто по-другому организовать цикл. Как - это, думаю, полезно будет самому подумать, ничего сложного тут нет :) См. обновление ответа.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10001; ) {
        answer += 2;
        if (is_prime(answer))
        i++;
}
```

Comment: Это я уже пробывал - не работает)

Comment: Рассмотрим `for`.

Comment: Не стоит. Посмотри на ответ вверху.